# Matlab function never ending on .net

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have to import some matlab functions to a .net web api. The matlab code was compiled to a dll using matlab compiler of matlab 2015b. The problem is when i try to use methods on the dll the process enter in a never ending iddle state, with no return or exeception. Someone already had something like it?

I'm using .net framework 4.0, in visual studio 2017, with this configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

The code was compiled using matlab 2015b 64bits, and everything else is also in 64bits (MWArray.dll, MRC 9.0).

Other things i should mention is that i already tried to compile simple matlab functions to dll and they worked, with the same setup. The code compiled to the dll is working in matlab.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. The person sending me the dlls told me it was built in 64-bit version, but apparently it was not. To fix I downloaded the 32 bit version of MCR and that was it. One thing to mention that was also a problem is that older versions of Matlab Compiler do not show this message:
[tag.m was a lesson](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djv1L.jpg)

So I had trouble exporting the classes, the solution was to encapsulate the constructor in a separate script to get the class structure.